# TestCafe-use dispatchevent to press Digit1 and Numpad1

Tags: javascript, testing, e2e-testing, keyboard-events, testcafe

Gretting all.In TestCafe,there are `pressKey()`and`dispatchevent()`to use on press keyboard .I'm now struggling on one thing:I can't press the Numpad by neither `pressKey()` or `dispatchevent()`.Here's what I've tried:

```
.dispatchEvent(#textbox,'keydown',{code:'numpad1'})
```

This actually fired,but it didn't type in the text `1` by the `numpad1`.Same thing on `Digit1`.Want to know if TestCafe support the different pressKey by Numpad and Digit?Thanks for reply.

Edit:
I tried to use `dispatchevent()` [Here](https://en.key-test.ru/) to fire `Digit1` and `numpad1`,it works good,but if i tried on www.google.com,it fails.

Answer (score 0):

Typing text via dispatching keyboard events is not allowed due to security reasons. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent#Auto-repeat_handling_prior_to_Gecko_5.0. That's why the 'keydown' event is raised, but no value appears in the text box.

To simulate an input process with required key events, you can use the approach described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69917022/10684943.

Comment: Thanks for reply!The apptoach you provided may not fit my request since it is use on develop side,but mine is on e2e-test side,on ```document```,the compiler gives error.

Comment: I gave that link just for illustration. You can simulate a set of events (keydown, keypress, input, keyup) using the dispatchEvent method or the [ClientFunction](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402832/guides/basic-guides/client-functions). As you can see in that answer, the value of the textBox should be changed manually.