# How to use Vue to implement the recording and playback functions of the mouse and keyboard?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I can't simulate keyboard pressing no matter what, even if my input is already focused! Under normal circumstances, focusing on the input is sufficient, but now focusing on the analog input is not possible. I use a simulated keyboard:

```js
const simulatePress = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {
    key: event.key, // Specify the desired key
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true
});
// Dispatch the event on the target element
document.dispatchEvent(simulatePress);
```

But it still doesn't work!
I hope the big shots can give me an answer, I really have no choice.

My complete Vue2 code:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="mouse-keyboard-tracker">
      <button class="doclick" @click="dome">click</button>
      <div style="width: 100%; height: 25vh; overflow: scroll;">
        <div>{{ events }}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="fakeMouse" ref="fakeMouse" style="position: absolute; width: 20px; height: 20px; background-color: rgb(214, 58, 58); border-radius: 100%;"></div>
    <button @click="startReplay">Replay Events</button>
    <input id="fakeInput" style="height: 40px;" type="text">
    <input id="Input" style="height: 40px;" type="text">
    <p>{{ visTxt }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      events: [],
      visTxt: [],
      currentIndex: 0,
      isReplaying: false
    };
  },
  mounted () {
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', this.handleMouseEvent);
    document.addEventListener('click', this.handleMouseEvent);
    document.addEventListener('keydown', this.handleKeyDown);
  },
  methods: {
    dome() {
      this.visTxt.push("demo")
    },
    handleMouseEvent(event) {
      if (event.type === 'mousemove') {
        this.events.push({ type: 'mouse', action: 'move', x: event.clientX, y: event.clientY });
      } else if (event.type === 'click') {
        this.events.push({ type: 'mouse', action: 'click', x: event.clientX, y: event.clientY });
      }
      this.displayEvents();
    },
    handleKeyDown (event) {
     
    this.events.push({ type: 'keyboard', key: event.key });
    this.displayEvents();
      
    },
    displayEvents() {
      // No need to log to console, events are displayed on the page
    },
    startReplay () {
      this.currentIndex = 0;
      this.replayNextEvent();
      document.removeEventListener('mousemove', this.handleMouseEvent);
      document.removeEventListener('click', this.handleMouseEvent);
      document.removeEventListener('keydown', this.handleKeyDown);
    },
    replayNextEvent () {
      const event = this.events[this.currentIndex];
      if (event) {
        if (event.type === 'mouse') {
          if (event.action === 'move') {
            this.$refs.fakeMouse.style.left = event.x + 'px';
            this.$refs.fakeMouse.style.top = event.y + 'px';
          } else if (event.action === 'click') {
            this.performFakeClick(event);
          }
        } else if (event.type === 'keyboard') {
          // Create a new keyboard event
          const simulatePress = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {
            key: event.key, // Specify the desired key
            bubbles: true,
            cancelable: true
          });
          // Dispatch the event on the target element
          document.dispatchEvent(simulatePress);
          
        }
        // Delete executed events
        this.events.splice(this.currentIndex, 1);
        // Set timeout for next event
        setTimeout(this.replayNextEvent, 20); 
      }
      
    },
    performFakeClick (event) {
      let targetElement = document.elementFromPoint(event.x, event.y);
      if (targetElement.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'input') {
        // foucs element wait simulate key press
        targetElement.focus()
      }
      
      if (this.targetElement) {
        const clickEvent = new MouseEvent('click', {
          bubbles: true,
          cancelable: true,
          view: window
        });
        this.targetElement.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
      }
    }
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    document.removeEventListener('mousemove', this.handleMouseEvent);
    document.removeEventListener('click', this.handleMouseEvent);
    document.removeEventListener('keydown', this.handleKeyDown);
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.mouse-keyboard-tracker {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
</style>
```

Comment: There are multiple events that occur when you press a key on an input, and to truly replicate an input you must reproduce that full event "stack".  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69917022/6225326)

Comment: thank u so much!solve my problem!thank u!